# Maximum possible value for f64?

Tags: max, rust, min

How can I initialize a variable of type `f64` with the maximum possible value? I already tried things like:

```
std::f64::MAX
f64::MAX_VALUE
f64::consts::MAX_VALUE
core::f64::MAX_VALUE
```

and some other variants but the compiler always complains about an unresolved name. I'm using no namespaces (like no `use xx::yyy`) and I'm trying to initialize the variable like this:

```
let mut min = f64::consts::MAX_VALUE;
```

Did I miss something or is there no way to get the largest possible value for a f64?

If there is a way for `f64`, what are the ways for the other data types?

Comment: You should always post the *exact* error messages you're seeing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [`std::f64` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/), the following should be what you want:

```
std::f64::MAX
```

which is declared as:

```
pub const MAX: f64 = 1.7976931348623157e+308_f64
```

It can be used like:

```
fn main() {
    let mut min = std::f64::MAX;
}
```

I found this by searching Google for "f64 maximum value rust".

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I only found [this documentation page](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/index.html).. Your code is working, I'll accept the answer as soon as SO allows it :P

Comment: @BafTac: The page you found indicates those values are imported from `core::f64`, which is: http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/f64/index.html

Comment: `std::f64::MAX` is depricated, use `f64::MAX` instead